# Forgetful functor from Grp to Set is faithful

Tags: category-theory

I have read that the forgetful functor from Grp to Set is faithful. Part of this means that the map from a group to its underlying set is injective. But I don't see how this is the case.

Let $(G,\cdot)$ be a non-abelian group. Now define an operation $*$ on $G$ by 
$$ g*h=h.g\quad \forall g,h\in G$$
Then $(G,*)$ is also a group with the same underlying set $G$. Hence the forgetful functor maps both of these groups to $G$ and is not injective. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, I misunderstood the definition. The map to the underlying set does not need to be injective. Its the morphisms which must satisfy an injectivity requirement.

Comment: Indeed all forgetful functors are faithful.

Comment: This is true only if the "domain" category of the forgetful functor has objects which are sets with some extra structure for example $\textbf{Grp}$ or $\textbf{Top}$ etc.